# Sign-In with google for games services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-signin

I am implementing the new sign in with google flow according to this blog post: [api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html)

However on sign in I get the following exception:

`IllegalStateException: Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API`

I am constructing my `GoogleApiClient` like this:

```
final GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .build();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .build();
```

When I remove `.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)` I get the following exceptoin:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Appropriate Api was not requested.`

Am I missing something or the new flow does not support `Games.API`?

Comment: Pls read https://plus.google.com/+EtienneLawlor/posts/AB9rq2B69k3

Comment: And this link http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html, you can pay attention to `Issue: Asking for unnecessary scopes` and `Solution: Ask only for the scopes you need`

Comment: What unnecessary scope am I asking for here?

Comment: @maclir have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @VladimirKulyk From what I understood this flow is not supported for games.

Comment: @maclir see how I resolve this problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317695/auth-google-sign-in-api-cannot-be-used-with-games-api)

Comment: I created an issue on android issue tracker suggesting the new Google sign-in flow to be integrated with Game API: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225329 give it a star if you think it is a good idea ;)

Comment: I got it working. Check out this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you can refer to the following sample code:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_games);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i("Result", "onConnected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Attempt to reconnect
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e("Result", "onConnectionFailed");

    // If the connection failed, in most of time this means user hasn't logined yet
    // In this case invoke the `startResolutionForResult` will launch the login dialog and account picker
    try {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(m_activity, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
...
```

More details at [Accessing the Play Games Services APIs in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init#setting_up_your_game_project)

If your app gets `java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information`, please read [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#unable_to_sign_in)

Some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This solution is not using the [new sign in flow](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2015/12/api-updates-for-sign-in-with-google.html)

Comment: @maclir The Game Play Games has its own login flow so the `new sign in flow` is not necessary here.

Comment: @jayatubi and maclir: please read [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html) for "Some changes are coming to Play Game Services in early 2017"

Comment: Try this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar error that was ask in this [community](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/+EtienneLawlor/posts/AB9rq2B69k3).

> The error message seems pretty clear that this isn't possible at the moment: Games has its own login flow. Is there a particular reason you are using both?﻿

Here is a reference on [Implementing Sign-in In Your Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin).

Comment: When I remove GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API I get this exceptoin: java.lang.NullPointerException: Appropriate Api was not requested.