# Google Play Games, Firebase and the new Google Sign-in

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-games, google-signin

My game is using Google Play Games and Firebase (for Rankings System, because unfortunately one cannot reduce the score in Google Leaderboards).

In the past I used the deprecated way to sign-in to Firebase via `Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName` and friends...

So I tried to convert to the new Google Sign-in, but apparently it cannot be used in conjuction with Google Play Games:

```
Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API
```

My whole goal was/is to get rid of Google+ dependency (as Google Play Games doesn't require it anymore) and the GET_ACCOUNTS permission.

How can I sign in to Firebase without Google+ and GET_ACCOUNTS - and without the new Google Sign-in? Can I? Perhaps creating two separate GoogleApiClients would be a solution?

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code to reproduce your problem, it'll be impossible to say why it's not working. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I simply ended up creating two separate GoogleApiClients: one for Google Play Games, and another for Firebase (using the new Google sign-in). I see no problems with this approach, and I got rid of the Google+ dependency & GET_ACCOUNTS permission.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. I'd like to learn more details from your use case.
How do you sequence the two connect() calls? (I assume you have to make two separate connect calls)

Comment: With 2 separate API clients, how do you prevent the problem of choosing a different google account or playgames account if the user has multiple accounts on his device? I could easily see a scenario where the two do not match.

Answer (score 1):

To use Google Play Games Api with Firebase follow these steps:

***Note: getGamesServerAuthCode is the recommended way from Google; although it's depreciated. They may have forgot to remove the deprecation annotation when releasing to general public.

Step 1: 
When you have successfully signed in; get the authorization code. You may use onSignInSucceeded() for example. Just make sure the API Client is connected.

```
Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(gameHelper.getApiClient(), [web_client_id]).setResultCallback(new  ResultCallback<Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    String authCode = result.getCode();
                    exchangeAuthCodeForToken(authCode);
                }
            }
        });
```

Step 2: Exchange that authorization code for a token.

```
class AuthToken {
    String access_token;
    String token_type;
    int expires_in;
    String id_token;
}

void exchangeAuthCodeForToken(final String authCode) {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, AuthToken> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, AuthToken>() {
        @Override
        protected AuthToken doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
                Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("code", authCode);
                params.put("client_id", "[web_client_id]");
                params.put("client_secret", "[secret]");
                params.put("redirect_uri", "[redirect_uri]");
                params.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");

                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.googleapis.com");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                    // Build the string
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; ) {
                        sb.append((char) c);
                    }

                    // Convert JSON to a Java Object
                    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                    Gson gson = builder.create();
                    AuthToken token = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), AuthToken.class);

                    // Disconnect
                    conn.disconnect();

                    return token;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AuthToken token) {
            // Authorize Firebase with Games API
            firebaseAuthWithGamesApi(token.id_token);
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Step 3: Use the authorization code to sign-in with Firebase.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGamesApi(String authToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(authToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: It can be a solution, but `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode` is deprecated and next network request returns token info without `id_token`  that is need to get `AuthCredential` that we need to login to firebase

Comment: I heard from some article that it was marked as depreciated and that they forgot to remove it. Not sure though. Im sure they are working on its replacement. But, I have yet to see it.

Comment: And how about missing `id_token`? I try some answer from here but can't get this field in responce( Ony `acces_token` is returned and when I try to pass it to GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential it failes with message that it cant recognize `id_token` here

Comment: Thats weird. Ive tested this on multiple phones. What version of google services are you using?

Comment: Another thing, make sure your using the correct web client id.

Comment: I'm sure in my WebClienId as I have only one. But PalyServices version... In logs I see that I use 8+ and 10+ together. I'll try to find out where is old version depency and try again, thanks

Comment: Go to your firebase console. Select authentication. Go to sign-in method tab. Make sure google is enable. Click on it. And you should see something that says web sdk cofiguration. This will contain your web client id. Then, update your json file.

Comment: It will be auto-genetated for you in the developer console. From there, you can get your redirect uri.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it)