# Google Sign In with Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I tried implementing Google sign in using firebase . I have gone through the documentation and watched a couple of videos but none of them worked. Whenever I click the Google Sign In button nothing happens. Also after successful login I want it to lead to the main activity. My app launches from Sign In activity.

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static Button googleSignIn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

   // Configure Google Sign In
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
           .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
           .requestEmail()
           .build();
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
           FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
           if (user != null) {
               // User is signed in
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
           } else {
               // User is signed out
               Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
           }
           // ...
       }
   };
   // ...

}

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
 }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   if (mAuthListener != null) {
       mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
   }
 }

  private void signIn() {
   Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
   startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
   if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
       GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
       if (result.isSuccess()) {
           // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
           GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
           firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
       } else {
           // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
           // ...
       }
   }
  }

  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
   Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

   AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
   mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                   // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                   // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                   // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                       Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication failed.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   // ...
               }
           });
    }
    }
```

This is what my gradle looks like:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

Comment: Can you please post some code or snippet what you tried? Asking question without code is vague

Comment: The documentation for integrating firebase google sign-in is quite clear and I implemented it following that. What is the problem you are getting.

Comment: Whenever I click the Google Sign In button nothing happens. I'm launching the app from the Sign In Activity. Then when I click the sign in button and after successful login I want it to go to the main activity.

Comment: Whats your problem?

Comment: I have the Google Sign In Button Displayed. The problem is whenever I click it, it does not do anything. It does not let me log in to my google account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my code :

```
 protected void signInwithGoogle(){
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            //TO USE
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            String personId = acct.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
            String personPhoneURL = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
 //                User user = new User();
 //                user.setUsername(personName);
 //                user.setEmail(personEmail);
//                user.setPersonId(personId);
//                user.setPersonProfileUrl(personPhoneURL);
//                user.setSignedInWithGoogle(true);

           // updateFirebaseData(user,personEmail);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriSerializer())
                    .create();

//                String userData = gson.toJson(user);
//                      EPreferenceManager.getSingleton().setUserdata(getActivity(),userData);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"There was a trouble signing in-Please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        }
    }
}


private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication pass.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomePageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What is default_web_client_id?

Comment: getting error on second argument of enableAutoManage -- " Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.signin.MainActivity', required: 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener' "

Comment: you can try using like this : .enableAutoManage(this,this) or something like this .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                 
                }
            })

Comment: make sure you activity implement GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener in case if you are using the first option

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

Step by step guidance is provide in this [blog](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/03/firebase-google-login-android/)

**Add these dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

// Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:src="@drawable/profileimage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#E02F2F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_google"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_google"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sign in with Google"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.googlepluslogin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ImageView iv_google;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ImageView iv_image;

    boolean boolean_google;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_google;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        listener();

    }

    private void init() {

        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_google = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_google);
        iv_google = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_google);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    private void listener() {
        iv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_google:
                break;
            case R.id.tv_google:
                if (boolean_google){
                    signOut();
                    tv_name.setText("");
                    tv_email.setText("");
                    boolean_google=false;
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profileimage).into(iv_image);
                }else {
                    signIn();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        try {

            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]

                        try {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        try {
            mAuth.signOut();

            // Google sign out
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (user != null) {
            String str_emailgoogle = user.getEmail();
            Log.e("Email", str_emailgoogle);
            tv_email.setText(str_emailgoogle);
            tv_name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            boolean_google=true;
            tv_google.setText("Sign out from Google");

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load( user.getPhotoUrl()).into(iv_image);


            Log.e("Profile", user.getPhotoUrl() + "");

        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: getting error on second argument of enableAutoManage -- " Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.signin.MainActivity', required: 'com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener' "

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal use this`enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this, (OnConnectionFailedListener)this)`

Answer (score 1):

For developer mode (Unsigned Apk):

---

1. Add your system sha1 key to your project in  Firebase console, and download the json.

   2. Add that json in your project, app folder.
   3. Go-to Google developer API console, Select your project and enable "Google plus api" .
   4. Now clean and rebuild your project, now check the Google login it will work.

For Signed Apk:

---

1. Generate your signed key (.jks file) and take sha1 or sha256 by that key and add it in firebase console, then download the json.
2. Add that json in your project app folder.
3. Now generate your signed Apk and install in your mobile.
4. Now check Google login it will respond you.

Thank you