# Android - Sign in with Google

Tags: android

I want to add sign in with google in my app , I wrote the code as you see below 
but when I touch the sign in button,  it opens a sign in activity and I choose a gmail which I want to sign in with, after that the program make the "failed" toast .

Note that : I get the googleservices.json from google api cloud
and I added compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

```
package com.example.win.mytask;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,View.OnClickListener {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Name : "+acct.getDisplayName()+" Gmail : "+acct.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868873/google-sign-in-with-firebase-android/38869417#38869417