# How to combine Google Play Games sign in with Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-games

We are currently using Google Play Games API in one of our games. We would also like to make use of the Firebase Realtime Database, but this requires to authenticate the user with Firebase.

The easiest solution would be to use Firebase Authentication (with Google Sign-in), but that is not related to the Google Play Games account that the user is already signed-in to.

From the Play Games API, you cannot get any info of which Google Account the user uses. You can also not use the same Google API client to connect with Play Games and Google at the same time.

We have also looked into the custom token feature in Firebase Authentication, but we are not using a server to verify the user. The on-device Google Play Games services do not deal with tokens and it would feel strange to include the server sdk on the client.

One could use two different API clients, but that would essentially mean that the user goes through two different sign in flows. In addition, it cannot be guaranteed that he would choose the same accounts for Play Games and Firebase Authentication when the user has multiple accounts on his device.

So my question is how can we combine Firebase Authentication and Google Play Games to have one coherent user?

Comment: @mortiz - did you find the solution? I am also planing to implementing something similar for my app.

Comment: @vijay053 No solution yet. Imho it is currently not possible.

Comment: @Moritz What did you end up with? I'm currently facing the same dilemma.

Comment: @vijay053 Still no solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in/41499987#41499987

Answer (score 0):

I follow this approach:
[Google Play Games, Firebase and the new Google Sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247959/google-play-games-firebase-and-the-new-google-sign-in)

I sign in to the Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API in the onConnected from the GPGS.

I was concerned about multiple accounts too, but if i change the account the user Player ID is changed too.
Thus I think the Google-Sign-In the Google Play Games Services Player ID and the resulting Firebase UID (with auth by Google) are in a save 1-1-1 relationship.

Only drawback: The user now need to give permission about his account informations once.

Comment: Is this an answer, or are you posting a similar problem?

Comment: I had the same problem and for me the solution works well, thus I guess this is an answer, isn't it?

Comment: I think if you have to ask if its an answer, then its a good sign it might not be. Your answer does have an opinion within it, which also suggests perhaps this would be better suited as a comment

Comment: Ok, I answered to the main concern the asking person has. That there seem to be no mixture of accounts.

Comment: I use phrases like "seem" or flag this as "my opinion" because I don't run 10000 of tests and all possible scenarios, but my testings might help the asking person to overcome this obstacle. I didn't use a comment because I wasn't allowed to comment because I am a new user. I do not fish for reputition or whatever. I see ne problem trying to help eachother, so what is your prob? Is it more important, that every aspect of the stack overflow post-rules are met or that we can help eachother?

Comment: I would not consider this to be the correct answer since you basically login twice instead of reusing the already present Google play games account.

Comment: totally agree, but for now it is the only option. maybe they add GPG acc as credential in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just did this thing. Try to use this code (don't forget to configure OAUTH2.0 in Google Cloud and Sync Google Cloud with your Firebase Project)

```
fun playGamesSignIn(activity: Activity) {
    PlayGamesSdk.initialize(activity)
    val gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(activity)

    gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated.addOnCompleteListener { isAuthenticatedTask: Task<AuthenticationResult> ->
        val isAuthenticated = isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful && isAuthenticatedTask.result.isAuthenticated
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            gamesSignInClient.requestServerSideAccess(activity.getString(R.string.oath_2_web_client_id), false)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String?> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val serverAuthToken = task.result
                        val credential = PlayGamesAuthProvider.getCredential(serverAuthToken!!)
                        val auth = Firebase.auth
                        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                    Log.d("Firebase Auth", "signInWithCredential:success")
                                    val user = auth.currentUser
                                    user?.let {
                                        val playerName = user.displayName

                                        // The user's Id, unique to the Firebase project.
                                        // Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server, if you
                                        // have one; use FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
                                        val uid = user.uid
                                        Log.d("Firebase Auth", "$playerName, $uid")
                                    }


                                } else {
                                    Log.w("Firebase Auth", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                                }
                            }
                    } else {
                        // Failed to retrieve authentication code.
                    }
                }
            Log.d("Firebase Auth", "Google Play auth:success")

        } else {
            Log.e("Firebase Auth", "Google Play auth:failed")
        }
    }
}
```