# Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-api-client, google-signin

I'm trying to connect `GoogleApiClient` with `Games.API` and `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` (for getting User Profile Information).
Getting this Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API
```

---

Code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestProfile()
                .build();

googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(onConnectionFailedListener)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

---

Why I can't use `Games.API` with `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API`?
What alternative I have to connect `Games.API` and get User Profile Information?

Comment: Have you referenced [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683554/sign-in-with-google-for-games-services).

Comment: @ShreeKrishna it's the same issue, but I didn't find the correct Answer...

Comment: I created an issue on android issue tracker suggesting the new Google sign-in flow to be integrated with Game API: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225329 give it a star if you think it is a good idea ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved by my self.
No need to add `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` for getting User Profile Information if you already connected `Games.API`.

---

Connect:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(onConnectionFailedListener)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .build();
```

---

If failed:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERR);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            googleApiClient.connect();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting()
                            && !googleApiClient.isConnected())
                    googleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

---

If connected:
Get User Profile Information:

```
String name = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(googleApiClient).getDisplayName();
Uri photo = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(googleApiClient).getIconImageUri();
//and more...
```

Comment: But without `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` I cannot get auth token. Is it possible?

Comment: @Alexmelyon i suppose no. This example just for getting user data on Google Games (not Google+).